# JSON Schema - BigQuery - What would my schema be (from my JSON file)? I cannot figure it out

Tags: json, database, load, google-bigquery

**Google Cloud BigQuery - Load Data via JSON file**

I am trying to load data into BigQuery (JSON Newline Delimited) **from a JSON file**.
I'm getting stuck trying to figure out what my "Schema" is/ which I should be using?

The JSON file, is a file of products.

What I have tried so far... 
NOTE: This is **JUST** for **ONE** product (of many), then it repeats the same pattern for all the other products:

```
[{"sku": INTEGER,"name": "STRING", "type": "STRING", "price": FLOAT, "upc": "INTEGER", "category": [{"id": "STRING", "name": "STRING"}, {"id": "STRING", "name": "STRING"}, {"id": "STRING", "name": "STRING"}, {"id": "STRING", "name": "STRING"}], "shipping": FLOAT, "description": "STRING", "manufacturer": "STRING", "model":"STRING", "url": "STRING","image": "STRING"}]
```

**NOTE:** the "image" key, is a URL to the image

**UNLESS THERE IS ANOTHER WAY...**
Is there a way to load the JSON file into BigQuery and have it "auto-generate" the table and dataset?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the CLI tool, then this is the schema for your data:

```
[{"name": "sku", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "type", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "price", "type": "FLOAT", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "upc", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"fields":
     [{"name": "id", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}, {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}],
    "name": "category", "type": "RECORD", "mode": "REPEATED"},
   {"name": "shipping", "type": "FLOAT", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "description", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "manufacturer", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "model", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "url", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "image", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]
```

You can save it in a file (such as "schema.json") and then [run the command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data):

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON dataset_id.test_table path/to/json_data path/to/schema.json
```

Where *path/to/json_data* is the path for your data. It can be either a path in your local machine (such as */documents/so/jsondata.json* or it can also be a path in Google Cloud Storage, such as *gs://analyzes/json_data.json* for instance).

The schema must be in your local machine or specified along the command line but in this operation, **it has to be specified**.

Now you mentioned in the comments for my first answer about a type of operation where BigQuery does not require schemas.

You can do so indeed only for [federated tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources), that is, tables that are created using as reference an external file (and these files usually are in GCS or Google Drive).

To do so, you first would have to have your JSON data in GCS for instance and then you'd have to create the table in BQ. Using the CLI, this command creates the federated table using as source the JSON data from GCS:

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=@NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON=gs://bucket_name/jsondata.json dataset_id.table_test
```

This command line does not have the schema specified and BQ does its best to find what it should be given the data (I tested with your data and it worked just fine but I could use only legacy SQL afterwards).

Keep in mind though that this process is not guaranteed to work all the times and also you should use federated tables only if such tables meet the requirements for your project, otherwise it's easier and faster to load this data inside of BQ and then run queries from there. In the second reference that I suggested, you can read more about when it's best to use federated tables.

Comment: To answer your question regarding "auto-generate"...

OPTION 1: In Google BigQuery you can either do it all manual via the Web GUI, but you MUST provide the schema to load and populate from a JSON or CSV file: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com

OPTION 2: In Google BigQuery (according to the docs) you can load a JSON or CSV file (via Command-line/ Cloud SDK): https://cloud.google.com/sdk/ and it will auto-generate and populate your "table". However, I wasn't able to quite figure that out either:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#auto-detect

Comment: hmm I think I understood what you mean. I've edited my answer. In general you can indeed make BigQuery guess what the schema might be but only in federated tables. Otherwise, you will have to specify the schema.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad it helped and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer was helpful to you, please mark it as accepted

Comment: FYI...BigQuery cannot use INT64, must be INTEGER (but that wasn't the issue).

Sorry, I spoke too soon...I cannot get the data to load.

Just to be clear. Do I need to create the table FIRST? If so, should the table be "blank" (which you can do via Web UI) or via the Schema, THEN populate the data? OR do I create the table AND load the data at the same time when using the CLI?

Second, does the formatting of the Schema need to be like you have it "line-by-line" like a "sentence" OR should it/can it be formatted like you'd see "code" (if that makes sense?) ?

Comment: Ok, so via the Web UI, I was able to create 2 different "test tables" that were "blank" just using the schema. One table with the JSON formatting you have above, and one table in a more structured formatting like "code". Both ways worked. NEXT...I'm going to try to do the same thing via the command line (with the Schema in a Schema.json file), and create 2 more "test tables". I'll make a comment on that in a few mins.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the schema, its not quite matching the "data-set", therefor throwing the errors, etc. I was able to succussfuly load sample data / schema Google provides for a tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#before_you_begin

Comment: Did it work for you? If you are not succeeding in creating the tables I suggest you posting a new question in SO so people can help you better by knowing what steps you are making and what errors you are observing.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

First, Will's solution is correct, and it will/should work **99% of the time**.

**NOTE:** the data-set (JSON file) has **around 5,000 + products, 15,000 lines of code** (depending how you have it formatted)

However, with this particular dataset in conjunction with BigQuery (the way it wants it), for some reason (not sure the **exact** reason) would *not work* as expected. I did narrow it down to what (I think) was causing the error. I believe it was the "catagory": ["id":1234,"name":"ipod", etc. ] section for *each one of the products*. BigQuery seems to be pretty "fussy" with nested JSON data, and you need to do it just right and via Command-Line ONLY (no Web UI).

As soon as I **deleted the "category" section** (along with the ids/names) for the data-set and schema, I was able to get it to load the data just fine.

This was of course, only a very small sample of the dataset, as I wasn't going to sift through 5,000 products, deleting each "catagory" section.

**SOLUTION - use a CSV file (*recommend being somewhat familiar with MS Excel*):**

**STEPS I DID:**

**NOTE:** **Don't** do a *right-click "Open With"* (in Windows) on the file.

**NOTE:** I imported the **whole (5,000 products) data.json file** as *delimited*.

- I opened Excel (v2016 in my case) **FIRST (not the file)** and
  created a BLANK spreadsheet.
- Click on the "Data Tab" on the "Ribbon" at the top. Select the option "From Text".
- Change the view/file type to see "All Files (".")" so you can see
  your "JSON" file.
- Make sure "Delimited" is selected, and 437:OEM United States (unless
  you need it to be something else), click Next.
- UN-select "Tab", and select "Comma", click Next.
- Then, your going to want to select **each column** (inside the wizard)
  and change the "Column data format" to "Text", etc. When you're done,
  click Finish.

*It didn't come in as perfect as I wanted (usually never does).*

**GETTING RID OF UNECESSARY CHARACTERS ([ { : " ") AND TEXT:**

- Did a **"Find and Replace" (Ctrl+F for Windows), Replace All** for
  each of the characters/text I didn't want or need. To do a "Delete",
  just **leave the "Replace" BLANK** (so it replaces the text/character
  with nothing).
- Then, I filtered and sorted my data. This allowed me to find the
  columns I didn't want, which was "catagory", "ID", and "NAME" (that
  corresponds to ID, NOT NAME of product).
- Once you get your data how you want it, do a "SAVE AS". Change "Save
  as type:" to CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)(*.csv), and name your file
  (to anything) myfile.csv
- Then you can just use the Google BigQuery Web UI (or command-line if
  you want). for "Location/ File Upload" you'll need to store it on
  either Cloud Storage or Google Drive if the file is too big.
  Otherwise, just upload from your local computer.

**ALSO!!!! DON'T FORGET!!!**

- Under Options, select **"Comma"**, and put a **"1" in "Header rows to skip"**
  (this will be the name at the top of each of your columns. you don't
  want to import the column names as data. They are just to help keep
  things straightened out and sorted.