# Definition/documentation for BigQuery schemas?

Tags: google-bigquery

Does anyone know where the documentation is for the definition of BigQuery schemas? In other words, the JSON schema you supply when uploading files - [`personsDataSchema.json` in this example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_json_files).

I have been Googling for ages, but I cannot find any documentation about the schema for schemas.

The closest I can get is [documentation about auto-detecting schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect). But in cases where that is not appropriate and you need to supply a pre-defined JSON schema, is there any documentation about which fields are required and which values are allowed?

Comment: New line delimited JSON is the basis, and then all the normal fields/types. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902054/json-schema-bigquery-what-would-my-schema-be-from-my-json-file-i-cannot-f

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you mind create a feature request for it? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0. 

In the meanwhile, you can refer to the documentation for APIs. For example, this link  defines the schema of a table: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#schema. Not a direct definition on JSON but you can figure it out.

Comment: @HuaZhang thanks, I've created an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To define a schema, all you need basically is to define 3 fields: `name`, `type` and `mode`.

Each field in your table must have defined these 3 keys. If you have for instance a table like:

```
user_id    source
1          search
2          email
```

Then the schema could be defined as:

```
[{"name": "user_id", "type": "INT64", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
 {"name": "source", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]
```

The key `name` just describes the field name, such as "user_id".

The key `type` is the data type, such as STRING, INTEGER, FLOAT and so on. Currently, BigQuery supports [these types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types):

- STRING
- INT64
- FLOAT64
- BOOL
- BYTES (enconding bytes gives you the string representation).
- DATE
- DATETIME
- TIME
- TIMESTAMP
- RECORD

Now, if you open the documentation, you'll see that we also have the data type `ARRAY` that is a REPEATED field. I'll discuss more about them later.

The third key, `mode`, can be one of these:

- NULLABLE (allows values to be `NULL`)
- REQUIRED (does not allow values to be `NULL`)
- REPEATED (this is the ARRAY field, it means that the field is basically a list of values).

So, let's take our previous example and add a repeated field (i.e, ARRAY field) to illustrate:

```
user_id    source    wishlist
1          search    ["sku 0", "sku 1"]
2          email     []
3          direct    ["sku 0", "sku 3"]
```

The schema could be defined as follows:

```
[{"name": "user_id", "type": "INT64", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
 {"name": "source", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
 {"name": "wishlist", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REPEATED"}]
```

And there you have it, the ARRAY field defined as a repetition of string values.

We are still left with one type of field and that is the RECORD field (STRUCT). These are basically the same, except that we also defined a fourth key `fields` for them. As RECORDs includes other fields, you must describe their definition as well; this is easier to understand with an example:

```
user_id    source    wishlist            location.country    location.city
1          search    ["sku 0", "sku 1"]  USA                 NY
2          email     []                  USA                 LA
3          direct    ["sku 0", "sku 3"]  BR                  SP
```

Here, `location` is a RECORD (STRUCT) with 2 keys inside: the `country` and the `city`. That's how you'd define a schema for them:

```
[{"name": "user_id", "type": "INT64", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
 {"name": "source", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
 {"name": "wishlist", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REPEATED"},
 {"name": "location", "type": "RECORD", "mode": "NULLABLE", "fields": [{"name": "country", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}, {"name": "city", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]}]
```

You want to have a REPEATED field of RECORDS? Sure, why not! If you want a REPEATED field for each `hit` your client had in your website for instance, you can define the schema like so:

```
[{"name": "user_id", "type": "INT64", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
 {"name": "source", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
 {"name": "wishlist", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REPEATED"},
 {"name": "location", "type": "RECORD", "mode": "NULLABLE", "fields": [{"name": "country", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}, {"name": "city", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]},
 {"name": "hit", "type": "RECORD", "mode": "REPEATED", "fields": [{"name": "hitNumber", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"}, {"name": "hitPage", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]}]
```

Given all that, we can finally answer your question, how would `dataPersons.json` schema be defined?

This is an example of a row of personsData:

```
{"kind": "person",
 "fullName": "John Doe",
 "age": 22,
 "gender": "Male",
 "phoneNumber": {"areaCode": "206", "number": "1234567"},
 "children": [{"name": "Jane", "gender": "Female", "age": "6"},
              {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "age": "15"}],
 "citiesLived": [{"place": "Seattle", "yearsLived": ["1995"]},
                 {"place": "Stockholm", "yearsLived": ["2005"]}]}
```

First, we have `"kind": "person"`. This is easy, its schema would be:

```
{"name": "kind", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED" or "NULLABLE"}
```

`phoneNumber` is a RECORD (STRUCT) field with two inner fields, `areaCode` and `number`. Well, we already saw how to define them!

```
{"name": "phoneNumber",
 "type": "RECORD",
 "mode": "NULLABLE OR REQUIRED",
 "fields": [{"name": "areaCode", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
            {"name": "number", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]}
```

Now `children` and `citiesLived` have the same definition, that is, they are both a REPEATED (ARRAY) field of RECORDs (STRUCT). Just as in our last example, this one should be straightforward as well; `citiesLived` would be defined as:

```
{"name": "citiesLived",
 "type": "RECORD",
 "mode": "REPEATED",
 "fields": [{"name": "place", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
            {"name": "yearLived", "type": "INT64", "mode": "REPEATED"}]}
```

And there you have it. That's basically all there is to schemas definition. If you are using Python for instance, the idea is the same. You import the class `SchemaField` to define each field, like so:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField
field_kind = SchemaField(name="kind", type="STRING", mode="NULLABLE")
```

Other clients will follow the same idea.

So to summarize, you always have to define 3 keys for each field in your table: `name`, `type` and `mode`. If the field is of type RECORD, then you also have to define `fields` and for each inner field, you again define the 3 keys (4, if the inner field is of type RECORD again).

Hopefully this made a bit more clear on how to define a schema. Let me know if you still have any questions regarding this subject and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Great answer! One little thing to add is that the default mode is NULLABLE, so when you feel lazy you can skip mode for NULLABLE fields.

Comment: When defining RECORD types in python, the list of fields has to be an *iterable* - note the _trailing comma_ after the nested field in this example: `bigquery.SchemaField('hyperparameters', 'RECORD', fields=(                 bigquery.SchemaField('payload', 'STRING'), ) ) `