# How to delete or empty a table that is in BigQuery using Python

Tags: google-bigquery

I am uploading a JSON file to BigQuery and want to do this weekly. However I want the table to be deleted or have the table emptied. I tried truncating but haven't been able to get that to work. If it isn't removed before re-uploading he data is just added in and then there will be a lot of duplicated info. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a new table and setting the expiration date in bigquery using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939806/creating-a-new-table-and-setting-the-expiration-date-in-bigquery-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can't truncate directly.

The `--replace` parameter to a `bq` cli load job has the effect you want, clearing out the existing data. Also referred to as `WRITE_TRUNCATE` when using  API mode.

```
bq load --autodetect --replace --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON mydataset.mytable gs://mybucket/mydata.json
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17645587)

Comment: Updated to full content answer. Can I have my downvote recinded please?