# Bigquery fails to load data from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a json record which looks like

```
{"customer_id":"2349uslvn2q3","order_id":"9sufd23rdl40",
 "line_item": [{"line":"1","sku":"10","amount":10},
               {"line":"2","sku":"20","amount":20}]}
```

I am trying to load record stated above into the table which has schema definition as,

```
"fields": [
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "customer_id",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "order_id",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "line_item",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

I am getting following error "message":

> JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0 at file:
>   gs://gcs_bucket/file0. JSON object specified for non-record field:
>   line_item

I want `line_item` json string which can have more than 1 row as array of json string in line item column in table.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is that your input JSON should't have a "\n" character, so you should save it like:

```
{"customer_id":"2349uslvn2q3","order_id":"9sufd23rdl40", "line_item": [{"line":"1","sku":"10","amount":10}, {"line":"2","sku":"20","amount":20}]}
```

One example of how your JSON file should look like:

```
{"customer_id":"2349uslvn2q3","order_id":"9sufd23rdl40", "line_item": [{"line":"1","sku":"10","amount":10}, {"line":"2","sku":"20","amount":20}]}
{"customer_id":"2","order_id":"2", "line_item": [{"line":"2","sku":"20","amount":20}, {"line":"2","sku":"20","amount":20}]}
{"customer_id":"3","order_id":"3", "line_item": [{"line":"3","sku":"30","amount":30}, {"line":"3","sku":"30","amount":30}]}
```

And also your schema is not correct. It should be:

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "customer_id",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "order_id",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "line_item",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "fields": [{"name": "line", "type": "STRING"}, {"name": "sku", "type": "STRING"}, {"name": "amount", "type": "INTEGER"}]
  }
]
```

For a better understanding of how schemas work, I've tried writing sort of a guide in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673189/definition-documentation-for-bigquery-schemas). Hopefully it can be of some value.

If your data content is saved for instance in a filed called `gs://gcs_bucket/file0` and your schema in `schema.json` then this command should work for you:

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON dataset.table gs://gcs_bucket/file0 schema.json
```

(supposing you are using the CLI tool as it seems to be the case in your question).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion! The schema definition you have here, I have tried that and works fine. I had that before, I was hoping to have whole line_item as an array of json values in the table and not array of strings. Is it possible to have whole line item as json?

Comment: What if we are storing a record type that doesn't have a consistent format? I am trying to store a map in json format.

Comment: @Shadoninja I recommend asking this on SO. IIUC probably best approach would be to save your data directly as a json string and then process it from BQ (you'll probably get better answers on SO).