# upload local csv to bigquery - sdk console

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I'm using BQ Shell in SDK Console to upload a csv to BQ.  How do I use a local file for data source & table schema?  These tools were installed Aug 2017, so newest versions I suppose.

command I'm trying (this is the template):
bq load

destination table I have.

Is there an example somewhere of what data_source_uri & table_schema look like when referring to local files?

I successfully created a table using the web ui, but it has a limit of 10M files & now I want to put a larger table

Answer (score 2):

If you run `bq load --help` you can have already a good view on how to use this command for your needs. For more information, you can check the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data) describing each method associated to the load resource.

Example of loading file from disk to BQ:

```
bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 dataset.test1 test.csv schema.json
```

test.csv:

```
user,id
'user1',1
'user2',2
```

schema.json:

```
[{"name": "user", "type": "STRING"}, {"name": "id", "type": "INTEGER"}]
```

You could do the same for loading files from your GCS like so:

```
bq load dataset.table gs://bucket/folder/*.csv schema.json
```

As for understanding how to define your schema, I tried writing sort of a guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673189/definition-documentation-for-bigquery-schemas/44751624#44751624), hopefully it's easy enough to follow through and get a grasp on how to define them.

Comment: Very helpful response!  Thanks for taking the time